# how do I share authentication on a rails/rack app with a node.js instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, node.js, rack

I have been trying to figure out how to integrate a node.js app into a rails app and having them share sessions.  I've so far only been able to dig up sharing sessions between sinatra and ruby on rails via rack middleware. Is it possible to to do this?

I thought of a workaround involving the ror implementing a rest service that "poops" out a guid that node.js can use to create its own session.  This solution however requires having model validations ad such stored in two seperate apps.

just wondering if there was a way to integrate them.

and while using a js based webframework like geddy or express is cool,  I have alot of existing rails code and 3rd party libraries such as active merchant that I would have to reinvent.

Comment: the easiest way is when you auth via one of them redirect to the other with the session value. Each domain sets it's auth_token and store the auth_token in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about using something like memcached to share a validation mechanism, for example set a session in rails and for every message to the nodeJs server a token is given, nodeJs checks on memcached if the token exists and grants or denies based on that. You would of course add the record on memcached from the rails app

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that the same as sharing authentication between two different domains like openid, facebook connect, twitter sign-in.

- from rails site do an openid like redirect to node.js with the authentication information encrypted inside the url and vica versa?
- I am wondering if it is not possible to use `Custom OAuth Provider Strategy` from [connect-auth](https://github.com/ciaranj/connect-auth) and vica versa because connect-auth is "Authentication middleware for connect". I haven't figured the complete details out, but this might be an option?